# Flutter iOS not using pods

Tags: android, ios, cocoapods, flutter

im rather new to programming and flutter of course. I'm trying to get to work firebase pods in order to authenticate users within my app. Android and its "pubspec" worked like a charme, however i can't get ios pods to work. Whenever i try to use one of the installed pods i get the following error for example:

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method signInWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)

```
The 'podfile' and the 'podfile.lock' look like this:

        # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
        # platform :ios, '9.0'

        # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting 
        flutter build latency.
        ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

        def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
        file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
        if !File.exists? file_abs_path
        return [];
      end
      pods_ary = []
      skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
      File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
          next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*# 
     {symbol}/ }
          plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
          if plugin.length == 2
            podname = plugin[0].strip()
            path = plugin[1].strip()
            podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
            pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
          else
            puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
          end
      }
      return pods_ary
    end

    target 'Runner' do
      # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having 
    Podfile.lock
      # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
      system('rm -rf .symlinks')
      system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

      # Flutter Pods
      generated_xcode_build_settings = 
    parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
      if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
        puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install 
    manually, make sure flutter packages get is executed first."
      end
      generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
        if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
          symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
          File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
          pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, 
    File.basename(p[:path]))
        end
      }

      # Plugin Pods
      plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
      plugin_pods.map { |p|
        symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
        File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
        pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
      }
    end

    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end


PODS:
  - BoringSSL (10.0.3):
    - BoringSSL/Implementation (= 10.0.3)
    - BoringSSL/Interface (= 10.0.3)
  - BoringSSL/Implementation (10.0.3):
    - BoringSSL/Interface (= 10.0.3)
  - BoringSSL/Interface (10.0.3)
  - cloud_firestore (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/Auth
    - Firebase/Core
    - Firebase/Database
    - Firebase/Firestore
    - Flutter
  - Firebase/Auth (5.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (= 5.0.0)
  - Firebase/Core (5.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.0.1)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (5.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 5.0.2)
  - Firebase/Database (5.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDatabase (= 5.0.1)
  - Firebase/Firestore (5.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseFirestore (= 0.12.2)
  - firebase_auth (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/Auth
    - Firebase/Core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_core (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/Core
    - Flutter
  - firebase_database (0.0.1):
    - Firebase/Database
    - Flutter
  - FirebaseAnalytics (5.0.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseAuth (5.0.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseCore (5.0.2):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
  - FirebaseDatabase (5.0.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.18)
  - FirebaseFirestore (0.12.2):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - FirebaseFirestore/abseil-cpp (= 0.12.2)
    - gRPC-ProtoRPC (~> 1.0)
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.18)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - FirebaseFirestore/abseil-cpp (0.12.2):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - gRPC-ProtoRPC (~> 1.0)
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.18)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (3.0.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.1.4)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.1.4)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - gRPC (1.12.0):
    - gRPC-RxLibrary (= 1.12.0)
    - gRPC/Main (= 1.12.0)
  - gRPC-Core (1.12.0):
    - gRPC-Core/Implementation (= 1.12.0)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.12.0)
  - gRPC-Core/Implementation (1.12.0):
    - BoringSSL (~> 10.0)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.12.0)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - gRPC-Core/Interface (1.12.0)
  - gRPC-ProtoRPC (1.12.0):
    - gRPC (= 1.12.0)
    - gRPC-RxLibrary (= 1.12.0)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.0)
  - gRPC-RxLibrary (1.12.0)
  - gRPC/Main (1.12.0):
    - gRPC-Core (= 1.12.0)
    - gRPC-RxLibrary (= 1.12.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.1.15)
  - leveldb-library (1.20)
  - nanopb (0.3.8):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.8)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.8)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.8)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.8)
  - Protobuf (3.5.0)
  - url_launcher (0.0.1):
    - Flutter

DEPENDENCIES:
  - cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)
  - firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`)
  - firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)
  - firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`)
  - Flutter (from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`)
  - url_launcher (from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`)

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git:
    - BoringSSL
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseDatabase
    - FirebaseFirestore
    - FirebaseInstanceID
    - GoogleToolboxForMac
    - gRPC
    - gRPC-Core
    - gRPC-ProtoRPC
    - gRPC-RxLibrary
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - leveldb-library
    - nanopb
    - Protobuf

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  cloud_firestore:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios"
  firebase_auth:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios"
  firebase_core:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios"
  firebase_database:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios"
  Flutter:
    :path: ".symlinks/flutter/ios"
  url_launcher:
    :path: ".symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  BoringSSL: c46efb47593135382bc0934196f16d2f726f5f36
  cloud_firestore: a2d49d9c7219fce31033eb1a2ee953d7733c91d6
  Firebase: e08fb0795f35707aeb1d8a715c731c45bdf6fd56
  firebase_auth: 27a5a77a032d557c18f8e223aaf8ec1368f6cdbc
  firebase_core: c96aa8b2fcf7f5167d32f22034f502f9304952b8
  firebase_database: dd62ab9f71967c9011ce2fd03a89e762dcc364df
  FirebaseAnalytics: b3628aea54c50464c32c393fb2ea032566e7ecc2
  FirebaseAuth: acbeef02fe7c3a26624e309849f3fe30c84115af
  FirebaseCore: b81044df1044c0857a0737c6324678b72d4f7f00
  FirebaseDatabase: 482bad9c2abd422bb2321194fb8c937e67426a89
  FirebaseFirestore: 93b8bf70484c92c271ae93940fe1e2ca9e35f92b
  FirebaseInstanceID: 83e0040351565df711a5db3d8ebe5ea21aca998a
  Flutter: 9d0fac939486c9aba2809b7982dfdbb47a7b0296
  GoogleToolboxForMac: 91c824d21e85b31c2aae9bb011c5027c9b4e738f
  gRPC: 9362451032695e2dfb7bafcd3740e3a27939e4ff
  gRPC-Core: 9696b220565b283e021cf2722d473a4a74b7622a
  gRPC-ProtoRPC: a1bd56fb1991a8dae4581250d7259eddabb66779
  gRPC-RxLibrary: 1ed5314e8b38cd6e55c9bfa048387136ae925ce9
  GTMSessionFetcher: 5fa5b80fd20e439ef5f545fb2cb3ca6c6714caa2
  leveldb-library: 08cba283675b7ed2d99629a4bc5fd052cd2bb6a5
  nanopb: 5601e6bca2dbf1ed831b519092ec110f66982ca3
  Protobuf: 8a9838fba8dae3389230e1b7f8c104aa32389c03
  url_launcher: 92b89c1029a0373879933c21642958c874539095

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 1e5af4103afd21ca5ead147d7b81d06f494f51a2

COCOAPODS: 1.5.3
```

> Flutter Doctor: [✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.4
>   17E199, locale de-DE)
>       • Flutter version 0.4.4 at /Users/jonasscholz/Entwicklung/flutter
>       • Framework revision f9bb4289e9 (3 weeks ago), 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
>       • Engine revision 06afdfe54e
>       • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58
>
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   27.0.3)
>       • Android SDK at /Users/jonasscholz/Library/Android/sdk
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
>       • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
>       ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
>
> [✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4)
>       • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>       • Xcode 9.4, Build version 9F1027a
>       • ios-deploy 1.9.2
>       • CocoaPods version 1.5.3
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
>       • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
>       • Flutter plugin version 25.0.1
>       • Dart plugin version 173.4700
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
>
> [✓] Connected devices (2 available)
>       • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                            • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)
>       • Jonass iPhone             • 56aec322364a426af796f324c15095dd3df68883 • ios         • iOS 11.3
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

I would be really glad if someone helped me out here!

Comment: What's about your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: `dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  firebase_database: ^0.4.1
  firebase_core: any
  firebase: ^4.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.7.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.5.10
  date_format: ^1.0.4
  qr_flutter: ^1.1.1
  url_launcher: ^3.0.2
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter`
@hunghd

Comment: Did u solved this?

Comment: unfortunately no @Slim_user71169

Answer (score 1):

first try **flutter packages get**
then in **pods folder** open terminal.

exceute commands pod install or pod update

then open **xcodeproject** file and **clean** project then **build**

Answer (score 0):

Have you:
 1. include the dependency for firebase auth in your pubspec.yaml and try 'flutter packages get' and 'flutter packages upgrade'
 2. Update your xcode and install the optional tools

Answer (score 0):

try steps:

Open terminal then cd to the project

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter build ios

cd ios

pod install --verbose

pod update
```